# Button "Use as Defaults" are missing in View Options panel (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, defaults

I'm a very new user of Apple and Mac OS - coming straight from Windows so please bear with me if my question is a bit foolished.

I'm looking for a way to set my View Option as a default property applying for all folders on my system. I've google this and every answer I'm getting points that I need to press the button "Use as Defaults" in the View Options windows.

Unfortuneately and strangely I do not have that button. I press CMD+J and I've the option to set all my View properties but no button.

I've attached a screenshot of my View Option panel and hopefully it shows it correctly, I couldn't quite figure how to make a screenshot either :-)

Cheers

[image: View Options Panel]

Comment: Screenshot is cmd+shift+4  (that will give you a cursor to select the area)

Comment: View Options is Only in Finder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the simple reason:

[image]

You are in this view and it does not have the Default, it is already default.

Switch to list view to set the defaults for it.

Comment: Ah that's annoying.. I really like the column view setting but want it to filter and sort it first by kind and then by name but I guess I would have to set this manually for each new folder I'm in.. But thank you so much for your answer :-)

Comment: @Mestika, you can still sort them by your desire using the ACTION.